# Windows 8 'setx' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-8, environment-variables

I'm trying to edit an environment variable, but i'm getting an error that

```
'setx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I can use the `set` command, but `setx` is no-go.
I'm on Windows 8.1

Any help is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using it wrong. Just typing `setx` isn't going to cut it, as the command prompt will believe that it is a program. As it doesn't find it, it gives off that error message.

The correct ways to use setx can be seen [here](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html), for instance. The main part is that after `setx` you have to append the name and value of the variable you want to alter, for it to be evaluated as an internal command.

Comment: actually setx without an argument gives this output: `ERROR: Invalid syntax. Type "SETX /?" for usage.` Your answer seems pretty wrong; you maybe wanna delete it or strikethrough

Comment: I believe that both myself and the OP might not have setx on our machines or path variables, which explains the OP's error message. Although I used Windows XP when writing the answer (XP does not have setx by default), Windows 8 should have setx. Either the path variable isn't leading to it or setx has been deleted from the system. The fact that the OP hasn't answered in over a year doesn't help as well.

Answer (score -1):

Since [Setx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) is a system tool that usually is located in \Windows\System32 you need to check if the \System32 was removed from PATH in your Environment Variables (see [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)). Normally this shouldn't have happened.

If it is not in there, then add `C:\Windows\System32` back to your PATH.

Comment: Please explain this answer in more detail—as written, it's not all that easy to understand.

Comment: How does one check if \Windows\System32 is in the PATH environment variable?

Comment: @Mogget in cmd, run `set path` and it should show the path variable. Otherwise, go to My Computer -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables.